# Pickup values in XML node using T-SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to take value in each `<val>` tag whose parent node is an `<interv>` tag. If you see this below sample. I have two values in `<val>` tag 48 and 1500.

My query is returning 481500. I am showing a sample xml and query which I tried below. In some other xml, I might have more than 10 values - can anyonly help me?

Sample XML:

```
declare @xml xml = 
    '<maintask chg="U" identask="25/63/00/000/000/056" nrd="-" revdate="2013.12.05" version="B2,B3">
         <title chg="N">Electric hoist 136 kg</title>
         <mainlimi category="1">
             <limit msmgeographic="" type="TBO" />
             <nextperf>
                 <interv>
                     <msmlimitorder>1</msmlimitorder>
                     <msmtemporarylimit>False</msmtemporarylimit>
                     <val>48</val>
                     <unit>M</unit>
                     <margin>
                         <val>146</val>
                         <unit>D</unit>
                     </margin>
                     <marginmin>
                         <val>0</val>
                         <unit>D</unit>
                     </marginmin>
                     <marginmax>
                         <val>0</val>
                         <unit>D</unit>
                     </marginmax>
                 </interv>
                 <interv>
                     <msmlimitorder>2</msmlimitorder>
                     <msmlimitoperator>//</msmlimitoperator>
                     <msmtemporarylimit>False</msmtemporarylimit>
                     <val>1500</val>
                     <unit>HC</unit>
                     <margin>
                         <val>150</val>
                         <unit>HC</unit>
                     </margin>
                     <marginmin>
                         <val>0</val>
                         <unit>HC</unit>
                     </marginmin>
                     <marginmax>
                         <val>0</val>
                         <unit>HC</unit>
                     </marginmax>
                 </interv>
             </nextperf>
                <pnrlist>
                  <pnrdata>
                    <pnr wp6sourceid="4">76370-110</pnr>
                    <validity />
                    <pn>704A41815032</pn>
                  </pnrdata>
                  <pnrdata>
                    <pnr wp6sourceid="5">76370-111</pnr>
                    <validity />
                    <pn>704A41815033</pn>
                  </pnrdata>
                  <pnrdata>
                    <pnr>xna</pnr>
                    <validity />
                    <pn>704A41815035</pn>
                  </pnrdata>
                  <pnrdata>
                    <pnr wp6sourceid="7">76370-130-D</pnr>
                    <validity />
                    <pn>-</pn>
                  </pnrdata>
                  <pnrdata>
                    <pnr wp6sourceid="8">76370-140-D</pnr>
                    <validity />
                    <pn>704A41815085</pn>
                  </pnrdata>
                </pnrlist>
              </mainlimi>
              <desc>
                <para chg="N">LUCAS AIR EQUIPEMENT/TRW/GOODRICH.</para>
              </desc>
              <nrd code="-">
                <para chg="N" />
              </nrd>
              <climaticconditionlist>
                <climaticcondition code="-">
                  <para chg="N" />
                </climaticcondition>
              </climaticconditionlist>
            </maintask>'
```

My query :

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(TM.value('@identask', 'VARCHAR(100)'), '') AS MI,
    TM.query('title').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS Title,
    TM.query('desc/para').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS Remarks,
    TM.query('mainlimi/nextperf/interv/val').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS val,
    TM.query('mainlimi/nextperf/interv/unit').value('.','NVARCHAR(100)') AS unit                    
FROM 
    @xml.nodes('/maintask') AS TM(TM)
```

Result:

```
MI                          Title                       Remarks                     val     unit
25/63/00/000/000/056    Electric hoist 136 kg   LUCAS AIR EQUIPEMENT/TRW/GOODRICH.  481500  MHC
```

Expected result:

```
MI                          Title                       Remarks                     val     unit
25/63/00/000/000/056    Electric hoist 136 kg   LUCAS AIR EQUIPEMENT/TRW/GOODRICH.  48       M
25/63/00/000/000/056    Electric hoist 136 kg   LUCAS AIR EQUIPEMENT/TRW/GOODRICH.  1500     HC
```

Answer (score 3):

You have almost done it. Just use `CROSS APPLY` to get down to the items you need to query for the values:

```
SELECT ISNULL(P.c.value('@identask','VARCHAR(100)') ,'')AS MI
      ,P.c.query('title').value('.','NVARCHAR(100)') AS Title
      ,P.c.query('desc/para').value('.','NVARCHAR(100)') AS Remarks
      ,T.c.value('(./val)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS val
      ,T.c.value('(./unit)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS unit 
FROM @xml.nodes('/maintask') P(c)
CROSS APPLY P.c.nodes('./mainlimi/nextperf/interv') T(c);
```

[image]